# How can I retrieve one(or specify count) document per key with $in operation in sharding mongodb cluster

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I face some problem with my query in mongodb(pymogno driver).

Here is my problem:
I have to insert(update) about 100 million(100000000) documents to mongodb per day.
I gave up on using update the same key field I have to update append, and revised to use bulk insert (update performance is slower than bulk insert).

Here is sketch scheme in my db.

```
{_id:xxx, F1:1 , F2:"test1", TS": 2011/01}
{_id:xxx, F1:1 , F2:"test2", TS": 2011/02}
{_id:xxx, F1:2 , F2:"test1", TS": 2011/03}
{_id:xxx, F1:3 , F2:"test1", TS": 2011/04}
{_id:xxx, F1:2 , F2:"test1", TS": 2011/05}
.....
(4 billion up or more)
```

When I query, I just want to retrieve the latest TS group by F1(field1).

I know that "group" aggregation framework can do that, but I have sharding my db and group operation not allow in sharding db.

I also tried to use map-reduce to do that, but it is not providing good enough query performance.

The only query I am using is "$in" operation.

```
db.test.find({"F1":{"$in":[1,2,3,....]}})
```

It retrieves all docs in the target array, but i only want to get the latest document per key F1.

```
{_id:xxx, F1:1 , F2:"test2", TS": 2011/02}
{_id:xxx, F1:2 , F2:"test1", TS": 2011/05}
{_id:xxx, F1:3 , F2:"test2", TS": 2011/03}
```

How can I get that?

ps.
The target array might contain a million elements that I want to bulk query.

Is there is good way to do that?

Comment: Clarification: You've got 100 million documents in a collection. You want to return the newest document (based on the timestamp) for each value of F1?

Comment: Yes! that right just like group operation like
reducer =  function(doc, prev){ 
                if(doc.TS > prev.TS){     
                           prev.TS = doc.TS; 
                           prev.F2 = doc.F2;
                            } 
                       }
but group dosen't work in sharding cluster

Comment: Clarification: It is 100 million documents insert per day, and more than 4 billion in collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there's no single step solution to this problem as you can't use the aggregation framework in a shard as you mentioned (and it likely wouldn't perform well even if it did), you might want to explore a solution like:

- Create a new document collection which will be used as your index (but not an actual MongoDB index).
- Inside this collection, you will store one document per unique F1 value. The document contains a reference to the most recent Document in your primary collection. You can use a conditional update to create (when necessary) the index document or update it. Use a query to find the document and match only if the timestamp is less than (or equal) to the newest document being inserted for that value. (maybe
- You'd then use the "index collection" to fetch the latest document references for each F1 value.

Comment: I have ever been think this method before.But as my say, I have to deal with 100 million insert daily. 
As this index collection architecture I have to update each document if it latest document for unique F1.(but update performance cannot good enough for 100million daily income)
Or if there has another way to build this index collection that I miss? please coach me if there has good way to build that. thx.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If you have enough RAM to hold the working set and keep up with the writes, I'd think my suggestion would be reasonable. Whatever you come up with, you'll need to test it thoroughly.

Comment: okay thx!I will try your suggestion. Or maybe I didn't clearly indicate the difficulty in my status. Because I insert different F1 document daily with 100 million amount, and next TS F1 will insert to db next month. So I have to get the latest document with F1. But your suggestion gave me another direction to make a cache of index, I will try ti in POC, thx a lot again.